# Computed field value based on other column while insertion

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I have an `ID` column(primary key auto increment) and one more column for name.

I want to fill name column's value automatically while insertion based on generated ID column value in format

```
<IDColumnValue>_School
```

I am aware of the two ways to do this

1. using trigger
2. inserting the row first and then update its column value based on the inserted row id column value

But actually I want to make this field Non Nullable but to use the second option I will have to make it nullable.

Is there any direct way to do this while inserting row so that I can have the field non nullable?

Comment: Why don't you simply fill it first with a fancy value and then update it ?

Comment: Why you not want use trigger&

Comment: @MichaelKazarian - Trigger can update the inserted row name column just after it gets inserted

Comment: @YellowBird - Hmm your suggestion sounds fine, let's see if anyone comes up to do this in one query

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you can use a temporary value for the `name` column. You can use a request like :

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES('', 'name') /*let's assume name is the real name you want to insert*/
```

I'm not sure then how to use a trigger, but you may want to write something like this :

```
delimiter #

CREATE TRIGGER update_name_after_insert INSERT ON `table`
for each row
begin
  update `table` set name = CONCAT_WS("_", id, name)
end#
```

Answer (score 0):

It work for firebird but I think it [must work in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) because MySQL have `new/old` operators. Bellow trigger for table XYZ with fields B and C (not null).

```
CREATE OR ALTER trigger xyz_bi0 for xyz
active before insert position 0
AS
begin
  new.c=new.b||' some text';--this construction must work in MySQL
end
```