# MySQL use "Auto Number Field Value" in another column on insert

Tags: mysql, insert

Does MySQL allow you to use whatever the next auto number is in another column in the same query?

Column A (auto Number)
Column B (text)
Column C (int)
Column D (text)

INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','some text','THIS AUTO NUMBER','some text')

We are trying to use our "auto number" as the default value for another field. If this is possible can you share the syntax.

Of course if its not possible I can just run three queries, first insert, query for auto number used, then update, but if the functionality exist it would be helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you need to have the value of one column to be computed based on the just obtained auto incremented identifier. This does not seem to be possible directly, especially if you want that value to be changed afterwards (otherwise a computed column might do the trick).

Several answers are indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828162/computed-field-value-based-on-other-column-while-insertion):

- use a trigger is one option, but I would not recommend it for this simple case

OR

- create a [Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), perform the insert and then update using generated auto incremented number